# How do I add locale to ubuntu server?

Tags: server, locale

I currently have those locales:

```
locale -a

C
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

How can I install `ru_RU` locale to my server?

Answer (score 338, accepted):

1. Check which locales are supported:

   ```
   locale -a
   ```
2. Add the locales you want (for example `ru`):

   ```
   sudo locale-gen ru_RU
   sudo locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8
   ```
3. Run this update command:

   ```
   sudo update-locale
   ```

Comment: ...then run `sudo update-locale`

Comment: What do you do if it's not supported?

Comment: use ru_RU.UTF-8

Comment: Could you please expand on why are both `ru_RU` and `ru_RU.UTF-8` needed? I don't know much about locales.

Comment: If you work with php5-fpm you'll need `sudo service php5-fpm restart`

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, but I had to restart Apache to get it working...thanks!

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez: issuing `locale-gen` without the codeset generates, by default, ISO-8859-1.

Comment: I needed this for PHP's [`setlocale`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) and I also had to restart my VM for it to take effect.

Comment: For some reason command `sudo locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8` does nothing for me. As an alternative, one could go and manually edit file `vi /etc/locale.gen` to uncomment desired locales.

Comment: I had to run "dpkg-reconfigure -plow locales" also, as suggested here: http://squirrelmail.org/wiki/SupportingMultipleLanguages

Comment: `locale-gen` is part of the `localehelper` package; if it's also missing.

Comment: And `update-locale`... does what exactly? For me it generated a file with a comment. Depending on the release, you've got to either do [`locale-gen en_US.utf8`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/locale-gen.8.html), or edit `/etc/locale.gen` and do [`locale-gen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/locale-gen.8.html). Also you might want to change/export the LANG variable. `dpkg-reconfigure locales` seems to run `locale-gen`, at least on trusty. For what it's worth.

Answer (score 98):

I would go another route, which is IMO better suited to the Ubuntu style. **Use the packages provided**. There are packages for each locale, and they do all the work for you... no need to edit /var files, which I always believed were not meant to be edited manually.

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-XX
```

where XX stands for the language code. Installing a language will install also all the country-specific variants (for example, installing language-pack-it will install it_CH.utf8 and it_IT.utf8, installing for NL will install nl_AW, nl_AW.utf8,  nl_BE.utf8 and nl_NL.utf8).

Comment: I think that this is the best and most 'Ubuntu' way of doing this

Comment: But generating the locales provides stuff like localized date format, decimal separator, character sets etc. The language packs also provides translations, which is not necessarily the intention.

Comment: Agree with Oskar. Even stronger if you consider this installation is for a server - most interfaces will be in english anyway.

Comment: I was afraid this would also *change* the current locale, but no. Everything is fine.
Looks like the best approch imo.  I don't particularly _need_ "translations or other stuff", but if I specifically use a locale for some reason, I expect it to be complete.

Answer (score 54):

1. check which locales are supported :

   ```
   less /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED
   ```
2. Add locale to list of generated

   ```
   echo ru_RU.UTF8 >> /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local
   ```
3. Regenerate list (it will invoke locale-gen...)

   ```
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
   ```

Comment: I had to add the second column: `echo ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8 >> /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` (UTF-8 occurs twice) on Ubuntu 15.04. Otherwise, it works.

Comment: On trusty `locale-gen ru_RU.utf8` basically adds `ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8` to `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local`, and well, adds the locale. `dpkg-reconfigure locales` seems to run `locale-gen`, which in the lack of arguments installs locales from `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local`, the ones not yet installed.

Answer (score 19):

I've found locale-gen to be your friend.
as in (adding hebrew utf8 for example):

```
root@world:~# locale-gen he_IL.UTF-8
```

you can even rehash it like so:

```
root@world:~# dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

and check that you did good:

```
root@world:~# locale -a
```

I found this solution way simpler than adding stuff to text files, even though it is what it does.

Answer (score 7):

Modify `/etc/locale.gen`, uncommenting or adding the locales you wish generated. Then run `sudo locale-gen`.

You can check that the locales are added with `locale -a`, which will show all locales.

Comment: oh, my locale-gen created a tonns of locales, ignoring locale.gen file.
So use this advice with a caution.

Comment: The [trusty manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/locale-gen.8.html) say: "Otherwise it generates all supported locales." Although I'm on trusty right now, and it seems to consult `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` for a list of locales to be generated. Which contradicts the manpage.

Answer (score 6):

```
echo ru_RU.UTF8 >> /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local
```

I get the following message at point 3: "Error: Bad entry 'ru_RU.UTF8'"

This work for me:

```
echo ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8 >> /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local
```

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, I had that bad entry error for en_GB locales. I've updated my `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/mintlocale` file to contain the lines `en_GB UTF-8` and `en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8` (the extra UTF-8 was missing).

Answer (score 5):

Use Ubuntu language packs. All supported languages are available in default repositories:

```
apt-cache search language-pack
```

A full example of locale switching in Ubuntu (server) version:

```
jani@example:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
```

All available (i.e. already installed) locales can be listed with:

```
locale -a
```

My current locale is `en_IE`:

```
jani@example:~$ locale
LANG=en_IE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_IE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_IE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_IE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_IE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER="en_IE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_IE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
jani@example:~$ date
Sat Nov  1 15:36:51 UTC 2014
jani@example:~$
```

Because I didn't have ru locales I have to install ru language pack:

```
jani@example:~$ sudo apt-get -y install language-pack-ru
[..]
Generating locales...
  ru_RU.UTF-8... done
  ru_UA.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
jani@example:~$
```

Now the ru locales are available. The system default locale is set by editing `/etc/default/locale`:

```
jani@example:~$ sudo vi /etc/default/locale
# Created by cloud-init v. 0.7.5 on Mon, 27 Oct 2014 18:46:13 +0000
LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
jani@example:~$
```

Re-login and check your brand new locale:

```
jani@example:~$ locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
jani@example:~$ date
Сб. нояб.  1 15:43:45 UTC 2014
jani@example:~$
```

Answer (score 3):

For a small server that did not support the locale I needed (`locale -a` did not list it), all I had to do was run

```sh
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

which provided text-based dialogues that I could select from (page up/down, up/down, space to select, tab to OK, and Enter to save). It automatically regenerated the locales.

As others have stated, you will need to restart any process that needs the new locale.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have locales installed:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install locales
```

After that, just add the desired locale

```
sudo locale-gen pt_BR
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check which locales are already **supported** in your distribution. Open or `cat` the file `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` and copy the desired locale to be added.
2. on terminal enter `sudo locale-gen locale_name`.

   For example `sudo locale-gen de_DE.iso885915@euro`
3. enter `sudo update-locale`
4. Check if the locale is installed with `locale -a`

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't comment so I have to add this as the answer.

I needed to add a 'special' type of locale sr_RS.utf8@latin in Ubuntu.

Command:

```
sudo locale-gen sr_RS.utf8@latin
```

does not add the @latin to the available locales.
In order to succeed in that the command should look like this:

```
sudo locale-gen sr_RS@latin.utf8
```

The command:

```
sudo locale -a
```

now shows:

```
sr_RS
sr_RS@latin
sr_RS.utf8
sr_RS.utf8@latin
```

Pay attention to the syntax difference between the result of `locale -a` and the way it is added by `locale-gen` commands.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers…

If for some reason you need to add a locale that isn't listed in `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` (the same list is used as base for `/etc/locale.gen` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`), you can manually call `localedef`, e.g.:

```
sudo localedef -c -i uk_UA -f CP1251 uk_UA.CP1251
```

(`/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` contains only `UTF-8` and `KOI8-U` codesets for `uk_UA` but not `CP1251`.)