# Full switch locale: Ubuntu server installed with no locales, how to enable locales systemwide?

Tags: locale, utf-8

I have a **server** with no X, installed with no locales. There is a "C" locale.

I need to:

- run server scripts (no console involved) to copy, move and gzip files towards local ext4 file-system, which should contain files with special encoding (Czech, Korean, Russian etc.), so the UTF-8 should be enabled.
- see the file-names when I type commands in the console
- have possibility to type most of the file-names with special letters, when logged trough ssh.

What should I do to reach that state? Goal is to give complete guide to change locale systemwide (as default).

Comment: See if [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server)helps.

Comment: L- partially, but still there is default "C" locale involved...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have to investigate it deeper and this solution helps me to solve it:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

choose `cs_CZ.UTF-8 UTF-8` (default) and/or `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8`

```
apt-get install console-data
dpkg-reconfigure console-data
```

set `pc / qwerty / Czech / Standard / Standard` or any other on your choice

```
dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

set `Encoding to use on the console: UTF-8` 
set `Charecter set: Latin2 - central Europe and Romanian, Fixed, 16` or any other on your coice

in file `/etc/default/locale` set

```
LANG=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_ALL=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=cs_CZ.UTF-8
```

I dont know which steps are necessary, but after this all fonts and especially all ftp transfers and all tar-gzip actions work well.

Answer (score 7):

I would generate the English (United States) locale.

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

The system wide locales are stated in `/etc/default/locale` in Ubuntu, so give that file the contents:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: What about filenames? Still apears as  ?????.txt

Comment: Then are you sure the filenames are UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: (Did you reboot?)

Comment: @reboot: it is not possible without reboot? Actually, it is a server! And yes, unfortunate rebooted few times.

Comment: So, are the filenames showing up as ?????.txt UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: yes, actually, there is still LC_ALL=C, I will play wit that a while.

Comment: it directs me right way, but as answer it is incomplete. So finally, I will giv -1