# Weird directories are automatically created

Tags: 13.04, directory

I have one directory that is being created automatically in my home folder. I remove it and it comes back. Now suddenly another directory have been created and I can't figure out why!?

```
victor@guinness:~$ ls -l
total 64K
drwxrwxr-x 2 victor victor 4,0K jul 15 13:55 ??_$?
drwxrwxr-x 2 victor victor 4,0K jul 10 19:00 'a?
drwxrwxr-x 3 victor victor 4,0K jun 19 21:09 Apps
drwxrwxr-x 2 victor victor 4,0K jun 12 20:59 cbt
drwxr-xr-x 2 victor victor 4,0K jul  3 18:54 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 victor victor 4,0K jul  3 19:09 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 3 victor victor 4,0K jul 16 18:35 Downloads
drwxrwxr-x 3 victor victor 4,0K jul  3 18:54 Image-Line
drwxr-xr-x 3 victor victor 4,0K jun 28 17:45 Music
drwxr-xr-x 3 victor victor 4,0K jul 16 19:23 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 victor victor 4,0K jun 11 20:43 Public
drwxrwxr-x 2 victor victor 4,0K jul 15 13:55 sv_SE.UTF-8
drwxr-xr-x 2 victor victor 4,0K jun 11 20:43 Templates
drwxrwxr-x 2 victor victor 4,0K jun 12 21:10 Ubuntu One
drwxr-xr-x 2 victor victor 4,0K jun 11 20:43 Videos
drwxrwxr-x 4 victor victor 4,0K jul  3 18:14 VirtualBox VMs
```

When trying to remove them in the terminal:

```
victor@guinness:~$ rm "'a^A^?"/
rm: cannot remove ‘'a\001\177/’: No such file or directory
victor@guinness:~$ rm "??_$?"
rm: cannot remove ‘??_1’: No such file or directory
```

Doing `rm` and a `<tab>`:

```
victor@guinness:~$ rm 
^W^L_$^?/             .gnome/               Public/
'a^?/                 .gnome2/              .remmina/
[...]
```

So it's some weird characters. Also, the directory "sv_SE.UTF-8" was created the same time as "??_$?". Maybe it's a connection?

This weird problem started after an fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04.

What can I do to find what's creating these folders?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I've found that it is Transmission that is creating them!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: what is the folder content?

Answer (score 0):

The "?" marks are substitute for a symbol, which is not compatible with your character set. usually it is enough to set up UTF8 char-set system-wide. Use some file manager to remove them, for example midnight commander. If you wandt to read the characters behind ? marks, use following guide ([Full switch locale: Ubuntu server installed with no locales, how to enable locales systemwide?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298971/full-switch-locale-ubuntu-server-installed-with-no-locales-how-to-enable-local))

Your home folder is often used by some install scripts or installed software usually creates its own folder beginning with "." character (invisible folders - but probably not the case u have). What you send here could be some errorneous script running on start of some software. Delete the file/folder and try to catch the moment, when the file/folder is created. Then you will probably find the reason and source of your file.

Comment: Thank you, but I know these folders probably is created by some script and also about the char-set and that I can remove the folders by using a file manager. I've tried observing when these directories are created but I cant find anything. I have never had this problem before, with the same programs installed as other installations..

Comment: L- not clear what is the content of dir's so identification is even harder... Always the same filenames are created or different?

Comment: It's empty and i've concluded that it's transmission that is creating the directories.

Comment: Also, the dir's is empty and have the same names.

Comment: L- what kind of "transmission" ?