# How to Use Old Character Codes

Tags: wine, unicode, ascii

How can we use Wine (to run Windows software under Linux) with the old character codes (not Unicode UTF-8)?

Comment: *which* old character codes? `export LANG=C` should be the most ascii-compatible-english-only mode...

Comment: I'm talking about the old 850 code which was the compatible ASCII chart with latin characters (ñ, ó, í, â, etc.)

Comment: Hmmm... looking http://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850 and the file `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`, I do not think that locales that are not ISO or UTF-8 are supported. I do not know if wine has some internal thing, though. Will add the tag.

Comment: Could it be a 32 bit vs 64 bit issue? ???

Comment: I don't see why word size should matter here.... So no, it shouldn't. Have you tried it? I had very old programs running ok under wine out of the box.