# xfce or cinnamon doesn't change input language, yet lightdm and unity does

Tags: lightdm, xfce, language-support, cinnamon

When I try to change the input language on XFCE, or cinnamon, it fails. Although it appears as the language i am changing to is selected, the actual keyboard strokes still produces the language I was logged in with.

Notes:

1. When I change the language on the unity desktop or in the lightdm login, it is successful. But then logging into xfce keeps the chosen language frozen
2. It happened on ubuntu 14.04 and keep happenning after upgrading to 16.04.
3. On login I see a message saying "System program problem detected".

Any idea on how to solve that?

Thanks

Comment: What is the Layout setting of the Keyboard? You could have a look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server
Maybe that helps...

Comment: @WillemK, its hebrew (he_IL). I tried the recommendations there with no luck. It seems that the language pack is already installed, but something prevents me from changing to it

Comment: Umm.. that makes it hard for me to try and reproduce your issue in my VM, as I don't speak/read Hebrew. Do you speak any other language so you can determine if the cause is just in the Hebrew package ?

Comment: I can speak spanish. I just tried the spanish keyboard. It works on unity (producing the letter ñ), but it is not working when switching to xfce.  See this website for a virtual spanish keyboard: http://gate2home.com/Spanish-Keyboard. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Are you talking about the input language (keyboard layout) or the language which menus and messages are shown in?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, the input language

Comment: Ok, how do you change it when it doesn't work?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, I have a language indicator on the upper pane. I can use it to change the language. On unity it works. On xfce it shows that I change the language, but the actual keyboard strokes still produce the language I was logged in with.

Comment: In the PC of my wife (Thai) I added the item Keyboard Layout to the XFCE panel. As the default language is US English, the icon shows as the American flag.  Right-click Keyboard Settings -> Layout -> untick Use system default and then add the Thai layout. When I then click the US flag, it changes to the Thai flag and typed-in text is using the Thai font. Is this the behavior you want with the Hebrew language ?

Comment: ฯ้ม ฟืก ิั ะ้ำ ไฟั... oops.. and by the way... If the On Board virtual keyboard is showing, its keys also change to Thai font when I click the US flag to Thai.

Comment: @WillemK, Thanks a lot! So it turns out that the language-indication on the panel does not affect the XFCE language. While your suggestion works "Keyboard Settings -> Layout -> untick Use system default and then add the language layout"