# There are no additional languages available on this system

Tags: kubuntu

When I accidentally deleted Localizations via BleachBit, in system settings I can't add another language. And this massage pop-up: "There are no additional languages available on this system." How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you get this error.

`aa_DJ.ISO-8859-1...[error] cannot open locale definition file`aa_DJ': No such file or directory`

when running `locale-gen`

checkout this related answer

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299536/locale-error-cannot-open-locale-definition-file-fa-ir#299547

```
sudo apt-get purge locales
sudo apt-get purge language-pack-fa
sudo apt-get install locales
sudo apt-get install language-pack-fa
```

Answer (score 1):

First run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` from the command line to adjust your locales setting.

Then open the Languages module from the System Settings.

There is an Add language button.

you can order multiple languages in order of preferences.
if some translations strings are missing, it will automatically fallback to your next favorite.

you need to logout and log back in after adding languages

[image: beautiful plasma 5.18 - language settings]

Comment: Ummm... Did you see my screenshot? I can not click on this button.

Comment: @Dgir your image was camouflaged under "Please help". I've added it to the question so it's directly visible.

Comment: @Dgir can you check what your `/etc/default/locale` contains, and run `locale-gen` after configuring it ? see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server

Comment: FYI: I do not have any language-pack-* packages installed

Comment: FYI: translation files comes directly with application packages. `dpkg -S /usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/konsole.mo == konsole`

Comment: So? Did you found what happens and how I can resolve my problem, or you do not know the solution?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know what is missing on your setup...  did you run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` ?

Comment: I run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales anwser below`

I run `sudo grep -rn da_DK /etc`
This what I get:

`dgir@dgir-PC:~$ sudo grep -rn da_DK /etc
[sudo] password for dgir: 
/etc/locale.alias:42:danish          da_DK.ISO-8859-1
/etc/locale.alias:43:dansk              da_DK.ISO-8859-1`

Comment: I have the same. sorry I don't know

Answer (score 0):

@Mathieu J.
In /etc/default/locale

```
#  File generated by update-locale
#LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="ru:en_US:en"
LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"
```

From locale-gen

```
dgir@dgir-PC:~$ sudo locale-gen
[sudo] password for dgir: 
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_AG.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  en_AU.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_AU': No such file or directory
 done
  en_BW.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  en_CA.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_CA': No such file or directory
 done
  en_DK.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  en_GB.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  en_HK.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  en_IE.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  en_IL.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  en_IN.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  en_NG.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `da_DK': No such file or directory
 done
  en_NZ.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  en_PH.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  en_SG.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  en_US.ISO-8859-1...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  en_US.ISO-8859-15...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  en_US.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  en_ZA.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  en_ZM.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  en_ZW.UTF-8...failed to set locale!
[error] cannot open locale definition file `en_GB': No such file or directory
 done
  ru_RU.ISO-8859-5... done
  ru_RU.CP1251... done
  ru_RU.KOI8-R... done
  ru_RU.UTF-8... done
  ru_UA.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
dgir@dgir-PC:~$
```

Comment: since you already have `en_US` in LANGUAGE, I would remote the trailing `:en` at the end, maybe that will remove all the hits for missing definition for `en_*`

Comment: the `da_DK` is weird, as it is the only non english and non russian locale listen. to me, it is a hint to look for another config file hitting at your bug. I would `sudo grep -rn da_DK /etc` to find any references to that locale

Answer (score 0):

So. I delete ALL errors messages like

```
  aa_DJ.ISO-8859-1...[error] cannot open locale definition file `aa_DJ': No such file or directory
 done
```

because there are too many of them and the entire log does not fit in one comment. I left only those that were without error, to my surprise there was no English on "locales", strange, but there are other languages and Russian, which is my main language. So I do not know what to do, this so so frustrating, losing my mind here.

```
dgir@dgir-PC:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
[sudo] password for dgir: 
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_US:ru",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_ADDRESS = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_MONETARY = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_PAPER = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_TIME = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "ru_RU.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  bem_ZM.UTF-8... done
  ber_MA.UTF-8... done
  cmn_TW.UTF-8... done
  hak_TW.UTF-8... done
  mfe_MU.UTF-8... done
  niu_NU.UTF-8... done
  niu_NZ.UTF-8... done
  ru_RU.ISO-8859-5... done
  ru_RU.CP1251... done
  ru_RU.KOI8-R... done
  ru_RU.UTF-8... done
  ru_UA.KOI8-U... done
  ru_UA.UTF-8... done
  sah_RU.UTF-8... done
  tpi_PG.UTF-8... done
  unm_US.UTF-8... done
  yuw_PG.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8" LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8" LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8" LANGUAGE="ru:en_US:en" LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8" LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8" LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8" LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8" LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8" LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
dgir@dgir-PC:~$
```

Comment: Actually, the error is the hint to your resolution... I found this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299536/locale-error-cannot-open-locale-definition-file-fa-ir#299547  I have a feeling it will solve your problem