# Ubuntu Studio 22.04 - Startup problems sddm-greeter

Tags: boot, ubuntu-studio, syslog

I've got a freeshly installed Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS.
When booting, I've got lot's of errors.
Some of them are applied to sddm-greeter:

```
21.04.23 20:42  sddm-greeter    QFont::fromString: Invalid description '(empty)'
21.04.23 20:42  sddm-greeter    QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7ffd5767ab80), parent's thread is QThread(0x564b6c0fa9a0), current thread is QThread(0x564b6c1e3020)
21.04.23 20:42  sddm-greeter    QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7ffd5767ab80), parent's thread is QThread(0x564b6c0fa9a0), current thread is QThread(0x564b6c1e3020)
21.04.23 20:42  sddm-greeter    QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QGuiApplication(0x7ffd5767ab80), parent's thread is QThread(0x564b6c0fa9a0), current thread is QThread(0x564b6c1e3020)
21.04.23 20:42  sddm-greeter    QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.
21.04.23 20:42  sddm-greeter    Hunspell dictionary is missing for "de_DE" . Search paths ("/usr/share/qt5/qtvirtualkeyboard/hunspell", "/usr/share/hunspell", "/usr/share/myspell/dicts")
```

What does this mean and how can I solve it?
(I'm a newbie and have no experience in coding.)

**My System:**

```
Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-70-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-13700K
Memory: 62.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060/PCIe/SSE2
```

Comment: The error `Hunspell dictionary is missing for "de_DE" ` suggests you chose the wrong language settings (localization).  Try installing the localization setting for `de_DE`, command `sudo (locale-gen de_DE && locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8 && update-locale)`.
[How do I add locale to ubuntu server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server). Then reboot.